# The description in the CnosDB tiered storage document is inconsistent with the actual operation results

Tags: cnosdb

Document description：

first:

The basic unit of data migration in a CnosDB cluster is Vnode. The enterprise edition of CnosDB cluster provides the following commands to support tiered storage:

```
SHOW DATANODES;                          // Show all nodes in the cluster
+-----------+-------+
| DataNodes | STATE |
+-----------+-------+
| 2001      | HOT   |
| 1001      | HOT   |
+-----------+-------+

ALTER NODE [node_id] STATUS [HOT/COLD];  // Modify the status of the node
```

document link:
[enter link description here](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/latest/manage/tiered_storage.html)

The actual execution result is as follows:

```
oceanic_station ❯ SHOW DATANODES;
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| NODE_ID | HOST      | ATTRIBUTE | STATUS  | DISK_FREE | LAST_UPDATED_TIME   |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
| 1001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 28.22 GB  | 2023-06-02 10:21:16 |
| 2001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 28.22 GB  | 2023-06-02 10:21:16 |
| 3001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 28.22 GB  | 2023-06-02 10:21:18 |
| 4001    | localhost | HOT       | HEALTHY | 28.22 GB  | 2023-06-02 10:21:17 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+-----------+---------------------+
Query took 0.082 seconds.
```

second:

When modifying with 'ALTER NODE [node_id] STATUS [HOT/COLD]', the field is named 'STATUS', but it is displayed as 'STATE' or 'ATTRIBUTE'; can they be unified?